# designing bpmn web based designer using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, workflow, bpmn

I am looking for a web based UI for designing bpmn workflow, saving it as xml and to be able to integrate that with Angular front end.

As a first step for this I am looking to draw the bpmn shapes. Can any one tell me what will be the best way to draw the bpmn shapes using JavaScript? I checked with SVG, but using that seems you can only draw basic shapes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [bpmn.io](http://bpmn.io/) and their [bpmn-js library](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js) before trying to code something yourself. You would probably need to do the work of integrating it with Angular.